# is there any java 2 RAML parser available

Tags: raml, raml-java-parser

i am trying to solve the following problem:
lets say i have some java interfaces that i need transfer to Restful API Modeling Language.
is there any library that can help me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of these can help you:

- [RAML for JAX-RS](https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs)
- [Spring MVC-RAML Synchronizer](https://github.com/phoenixnap/springmvc-raml-plugin)